# Python JSON double quote errors

Tags: python, json, web-scraping

I am having JSON syntax issues when I am using the following code  code: https://github.com/clarkbk/streeteasy-analysis

Using this JSON in buildings.json

```
{
  "buildings": [
    {
      "name": "Henry Hall",
      "addr": "https://streeteasy.com/nyc/property_activity/past_transactions_component/799324?all_activity=true&show_rentals=true&style=xls",
      "id": 799324,
    }
  ]
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
2019-05-25 16:04:26,641 - INFO - Starting...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 27, in <module>
    data = json.load(f)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 299, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 9 column 5 (char 220)
root@LAPTOP-4QGC19OR:/home/HN/streeteasy-analysis#
```

I have researched for a few hours now on how to fix this but can't come up with a fix. I am not that familiar with JSON in general but I don't know where I am not double qouting properly. Appreciate any help with this.

Comment: `"id": 799324
    }` json isn't python, if there's a comma on last element it fails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line number gives a good hint

you want:

```
 "id": 799324
}
```

(note no comma after the last element)

json isn't python `ast.literal_eval`, if there's a comma on last element it fails, because it expects another property as the message states (`Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes` explains that, although the message could be better, as this error is very common)

If you have data like this, you can use `ast.literal_eval` on it instead, it will work without modifications (unless there are `false` or `null` json booleans/null-pointers)

Comment: Thanks! This worked, I also had to add a url definition in the JSON if anybody comes across this answer in the future.